# Oscilllator model in multisim

Tags: oscillator, multisim

What's wrong with this schematic? Multisim doesn't generate oscillation. Also I changed R3=1000, R3=500 but all the same.

[image]

Comment: I've edited the question to show the schematic but the darned schematic is to small to read!!!

Comment: http://img.radiokot.ru/files/100500/medium/gvy7vfj6x.png

Comment: Have you allowed enought time for the oscillation waveform to start building up - this may take several microseconds to hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: Yes. I think five minutes is enough. Maybe anyone can try this schematic at onw computer? I'll send design circuit, but I don't know where can upload it.

Comment: You usually have to inject some noise to start oscillation, or a cycle or two at roughly the oscillation frequency.

Comment: As another (more simple) method to enable oscillation start you should switch on the V2 source at t=0 or slightly later. Otherwise, the simulator assumes that the DC source is on since negative times (without any switch-on transient).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07I2-uWOS6E yeah, u right. but oscillations are damped now.

Comment: @Robert . Even I had a lot of trouble making my oscillator work in multisim ( various designs didnt work even after a month of continued efforts ). So I switched to LTSpice, and surprisingly, first attempt was a success. Maybe you can try this as well.

Comment: A lot depends on the integration method used by the simulator algorithm.  Gear integration for example tends to damp out oscillations making it difficult to simulate oscillators, but having some advantages for power control circuits. Backward-Euler will also damp oscillations, so trapazoidal is probably the best bet.   LTSpice allows you to select different integration methods, not sure if Multisim has that feature or not.

Comment: @Andyaka SE limits the size of images to about 630 pixels wide, but you should be able to right-click and select "View Image" to see the full size version.

Comment: @JYelton - read the very 1st comment - he obviously got a better version a bit later.

Comment: I think smt wrong with multisim or with me. See, I design class C amplifier, but what u think oscillator give me? Here: http://img.radiokot.ru/files/100500/medium/gxvq4vp66.png Small waveform belongs generator

Comment: @Robert, why not checking the loop gain response verifying if the oscillation condition is fulfilled ? But don`t forget to make a loading image at the opening of the feedback path.

Answer (score 1):

If it is configured correctly, then instead of having the supply at 12 VDC, make it step from 0 to 12 V at t=1 us -- then it will startup.

Answer (score 0):

Having slightly adjusted the circuit and selected the parameters, it started up perfectly and produced an excellent oscillation amplitude, almost 39 Volts from 12 power supply.[image]